# Copying one array into another then clearing the first array gives unexpected results in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array named `numbers1` with 4 elements and another array `numbers2` that is empty. storing elements of first array into another using equal to (=) operator should create a reference as far as I know. if there is a reference then clearing the first array should have an effect on the second with any approach.

This is my code

```
let numbers1 = [10,20,30,40];
let numbers2 = numbers1;

/* 
This only clears one array
numbers1=[]; */ 
/* 
this also clears one array
numbers1=0;*/

/* this clears both arrays */
numbers1.length = 0

console.log(numbers1);
console.log(numbers2);
```

The first two approaches does not create any effects on second array, but setting the length of numbers1 sets both the array to zero, the same happens when pop function is used on the first array.

The questions are

1. Is there a reference between these two arrays?
2. If so, then why does the first two approaches doesn't affect the second array but 3rd one or using pop with the first array affects the second one?

Comment: After `numbers2 = numbers1`, both variables reference the same array (with 4 numbers). But after `numbers1 = []`, the variable `numbers1` references a new (empty) array, while `numbers2` still references the other array (with 4 elements). Re-assigning a variable has no effect on _other_ variables that referenced the same object. By contrast, `numbers1.length` is length of the referenced array, therefore changing it affects all variables that reference this array.

Comment: In summary, the key distinction lies in whether you are modifying the array itself (which will affect all references to that array) or changing what the variable points to (which will only affect that particular variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The understanding of memory allocation is necessary to understand this

```
let numbers1 = [10,20,30,40];
let numbers2 = numbers1;
```

when this is done the memory looks like this

```
number1 ---> 
             [10,20,30,40]
number2 ---->
```

when you do any (**dot (.) operation**), it will refer the value in the address and then perform the operation

`number1.length = 0` will modify this array to this

```
number1 ---> 
             []
number2 ---->
```

but when you do (**= operation**), a new memory is allocated.
eg: when you do numbers1=0

```
number1 ---> [10,20,30,40]
             
number2 ----> 0
```

Hope this clarifies.